# How to return asynchronous operation from Coroutine to ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I'm trying to understand this last step.

I need an atomic one shot operation, I need to go to Firebase and place my user device token.

For this I just make a call to a method in my viewModel which will trigger my repo, but now, I dont want to use LiveData in my repo, instead, I want to just return Resource from there, but since is an asynchronous method I cant just return.

I want only to use LiveData at my viewModel nad not in my repository, the repository should only deliver objects to my viewModel and my viewModel should deliver these to my view.

### View

```
viewModel.userToken.observe(this, Observer {
            when (it.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                    startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome ${user!!.uid} !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    finish()
                }

                Status.ERROR -> {
                }

                else -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "error ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        })
```

### ViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val useCase = PostUserToken(UserRepo())
    var userToken = liveData(Dispatchers.IO){
        emit(useCase.postUserToken())
    }

}
```

Untill here, its working fine, now, from my postUserToken() method in my repo, I need to return a `Resource<Boolean>` object to my viewmodel, how do I do this with coroutines ?

### UseCase

```
class PostUserToken(private val repo: UserRepo) {

    suspend fun postUserToken(): Resource<Boolean> = repo.saveUserToken()

}
```

### Repo

```
class UserRepo {

    suspend fun saveUserToken(): Resource<Boolean> {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
            .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.w("saveUserToken", "getInstanceId failed", task.exception)
                    return@OnCompleteListener
                }

                // Get new Instance ID token
                val token = task.result?.token

            })

        //Here I need to return the Resource<Boolean> but wait untill it completes
    }
}
```

These are my two helper classes I use

### Resource

```
data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {

    companion object {
        fun <T> success(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.SUCCESS, data, null)
        }

        fun <T> error(msg: String, data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.ERROR, data, msg)
        }

        fun <T> loading(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.LOADING, data, null)
        }
    }
}
```

### Status

```
enum class Status {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR,
    LOADING
}
```

I'm always stuck at the repository when need to deliver objects to the fellow classes, which is the best approach to deliver this flow ?

I know that if I need to keep listening I should use Flow with Coroutines, but now I only need a one time operation that should deliver this object accross all classes to my view

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly valid for a repository object to return a LiveData. That's what I would do. I don't think you should should try to make it return anything synchronously, as that defeats the purpose of coroutines entirely.

If you want to use a Task with coroutines, look into using this library that converts play services Task objects into something that can be awaited in a suspend fun:

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services

Comment: Thanks Doug, but I have another question, like you said, I should also implement LiveData inside my datasources ? Because If that the case, I could do all my app with reactive programming instead of mixing it with coroutines, what is the benefit of mixing coroutines and livedata ?

Comment: That question is a bit too broad to be discussed in Stack Overflow comments.  It depends on the use case and your preferences.  I suggest taking that question to a discussion forum where there is plenty of time and space.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `login` from Activity or Fragment without any problem, then you should update your `MutableLiveData` to make your Activity aware of the changes.

What I've done to retrieve login from user repository and Firebase Auth is this:

**ClassViewModel.kt**

```
class LoginFirebaseViewModel(): ViewModel(){
    private val _loginResult = MutableLiveData<LoginResult>()
    val loginResult: LiveData<LoginResult> = _loginResult

    fun login() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                repository.userLogin(email!!,password!!).let {
                    _loginResult.value = it
                }
            } catch (e: FirebaseAuthException) {
                // Do something on firebase exception
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.kt**

```
class UserRepository(private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) {

    suspend fun userLogin(email: String, password: String) : LoginResult{
        val firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()  // Do not forget .await()
        return LoginResult(firebaseUser)
    }
}
```

`LoginResult` is a wrapper class of firebase auth response.

I hope this help you